# Ubuntu GUI Application

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, user-interface

I am trying to create an application that would  run on ubuntu desktops,I want a scenario where when the OS boots up ,it starts my application and its required services but the main ubuntu desktop does not show so it would seem only my application is running on the device,I need help on how this can be achieved links,articles,commands etc,anything that can point me in the right direction.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want a "kiosk" mode.  Googling on "linux kiosk distros" should get you started.  *(btw pretty sure this is offtopic for StackOverflow)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to understand what you are saying but...

You must distinguish major difference between runlevel startup and user session startup.
You did not provide any information what kind of application you have.

- **deamon** application should be launched by [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) script
- **user session** application should be launched by [.desktop entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in)

If you want to launch your application instead of regular session you can hijack X session launching pipeline.
At /etc/X11/Xsession.d there are 'shell' scripts. Last one **99-** calls *exec*. You have to provide your own (let's say 98-) script and make *exec* call before 99-. Scripts are launched in lexical order.