# How to start application after login on CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, upstart

I am trying to start GUI application with upstart script on CentOS. I have test script located /etc/init/ folder.

```
start on desktop-session-start
stop on desktop-shutdown

respawn

script
export DISPLAY=:0
sleep 5
exec /.1/Projects/UpstartTest/start.sh &

end script
```

start.sh scripts is running binary files for GUI application.

After reboot my computer. When I typed:

```
[root@mg-CentOS ~]# initctl status test
test stop/waiting
```

So my upstart is not runnig. When i type

```
initctl start test
```

manually it works fine without any problem.

How can I run this upstart script after user login (desktop started) ? I am trying to find detailed documents for CentOS for upstart but there is no.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404588/ubuntu-gui-application/9404735

Comment: @tripleee possible duplication of UBUNTU ??? I can count millions of differences between UBUNTU and CentOS!!

Comment: Not being able to run X11 desktop applications without a login is not one of them, though.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use the update-rc tool, which is builtin on linux distributions. It basically creates a symbolic link for the script you want to be executed at startup, or some other OS states, on the folder rc.X, where X is the number of the folder that determines a state that you want.

You may want to have a look at this answer: [Update-rc.d custom script running too late, and also runs at shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434089/update-rc-d-custom-script-running-too-late-and-also-runs-at-shutdown/24434477#24434477)

More information about can be found here:
http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts

Detailed information about the CentOS booting process can be found here: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-boot-init-shutdown-process.html;
the rc is being explained at this document as well.